# Installation of httpd-2.0.65

Tags: linux, apache-http-server

I have installed the package httpd-2.0.65(which is not a RPM package),but after installation when I am running the command

```
         #rpm -qi httpd
```

It is showing an output "httpd service is currently not installed in your system"
and when I am running command:-

```
         #service httpd status
```

It is showing an output "httpd: unrecognized service"

Answer (score 0):

So, is it a *.deb package? Try to convert it to RPM first with "alien" tool, or simply get rpm package for version you need, preferably with package management tool available with your system.

Your question should probably be moved to superuser.com or webmaster.stackexchange.com.

Comment: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/httpd-announce/201307.mbox/% 3C20130710124920.2b8793ed.wrowe%40rowe-clan.net%3E
I have downloaded the package from the above link and followed the procedure of installation

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you installed httpd service from sources (configure && make && (root) make install). Service wasn't registered in your system.
Try:

```
~ # chkconfig --add httpd
```

If there no /etc/init.d/httpd script for autostart httpd process, you need create it.